# Fitting a variogram for Kriging in R

Tags: r, spatial-statistics, kriging, gstat

I want to fit a variogram of my data for kriging.
Here is what I have so far:

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
require(gstat)

setwd("C:/Users/49151/Desktop")

#import data
data <- read.csv("kerpentest0909x.csv")

head(data)

hist(data$Z, breaks = 20, xlab = "subsidence rates (mm/year)", main = "Histogram of subsidence at Kreuz Kerpen")
summary(data$Z)

#if slght skewedness 
#data$Z.1 <- log10(data$Z)
#hist(data$Z.1, breaks = 10, xlab = "subsidence rates (mm/year)", main = "Histogram of subsidence at Kreuz Kerpen")

#convert data
coordinates(data) <- c("X", "Y")
#assigning projection
proj4string(data) <-CRS("+init=epsg:32632")

plot(data, asp=1, pch=1)

plot(data, asp=1, cex=4*data$Z/max(data$Z), pch=1)

#OK
#point-pairs
n<-length(data$Z)
n*(n-1)/2

#variogram
v<-variogram(Z~1, data)
print(plot(v, plot.numbers=T))

#fitting a model
vm <-vgm(psill = 1.5, model = "Gau", range = 40, nugget = 1)
print(plot(v, pl = T, model = vm))
vgm()
```

the variogram unfortunately gives me this:
[image]

blue line at the buttom is my variogram graph.
that's not good and I want to know which model and params would be better.

here is my data: https://ufile.io/lne90ray

Comment: see   [Fitting variogram models in gstat](https://r-spatial.org/r/2016/02/14/gstat-variogram-fitting.html)

Comment: If I try: `v0 = variogram(Z~1, data)
fit.variogram(v0, vgm(c("Exp", "Mat", "Sph", "Ste", "Gau")))` I get 4 times: `Warning messages:
1: In fit.variogram(object, x, fit.sills = fit.sills, fit.ranges = fit.ranges,  :
  No convergence after 200 iterations: try different initial values?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you read the whole article because it is written:

> I suppressed warnings here, as around 20 warnings were printed in cases with crazy initial values. This is usual for Matern models:

Therefore

```
options(warn = -1) # don't print warnings
fit = fit.variogram(v, vgm(c("Exp", "Ste", "Sph","Mat")), fit.kappa = TRUE)
fit
   model     psill    range     kappa
1   Nug    1.414452 0.00000000   0.0
2   Mat 2222.224588 0.05257203   1.9
plot(v,fit)
```

[image]

with [automap](https://rdrr.io/cran/automap/man/autofitVariogram.html)

```
library(automap)
variogram = autofitVariogram(Z~1, data)
variogram$var_model
   model     psill    range     kappa
1   Nug    1.484951 0.00000000   0
2   Ste 1013.993363 0.07317875   10
plot(variogram)
```

[image]